# can we stream audio using corebluetooth technology to multiple ios devices?

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, core-bluetooth, nsnetservice

Can we stream audio using Core Bluetooth technology to multiple ios devices? I am able to find and send small test messages to nearby ios devices.

Core Bluetooth Framework and NSNetservice (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetService_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNetService/publish) are used.

is there an upper limit in packet size? can we do live streaming using Bluetooth?

Comment: Bluetooth Low-Energy is not designed to send audio stream. Since CoreBluetooth.framework is for BLE only, it shouldn't be possible (or bad experience).